# HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath error

Tags: c#, aplicación-web

He hecho una migración del 2.0 al 4.8. Y ahora al cargar la aplicación no me funciona del todo bien ya que no me carga el css. Es decir la hoja de estilos.

Tengo esta parte de código:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        globalStyleSheetRef.Href = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + "/resources/styles.css";
```

No sé por que pero el `HostingEnvironment` me sale vacio y no localiza el .css. Es decir no me lo rellena y no sé por que ahora no lo hace cuando antes si.

También al intentar cargar la página me sale un error pero le he puesto manualmente que me abra una página y no se si tiene que ver con esto..

¿Que puedo hacer?

Tengo un error sin solucionar y es que cuando pongo de proyecto el sitio web me sale un error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Se ha quitado el recurso que está buscando, se le ha cambiado el nombre o no está disponible en estos momentos.

Pero lo que he hecho ha sido poner una página como página de proyecto y ya no me sale ese error, es decir entro en la página pero entonces es cuando no me carga el css.

Así que es cuando he mirado el `Page_load` y veo que `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath` esta vacio..

**EDITO:::**

El problema es que cuando hago la migración de Visual studio 2010 al 2019 no me funciona bien la app.

Por lo quehe descubierto el problema es con la hoja css, no se si de la forma que se carga ya no funciona con las nuevas versiones.

No sé que hacer.... :(

Comment: Cuando hablas de _del 2.0 al 4.8_...te refieres a .net framework?

Comment: Exacto, de un visual studio 2006 al 2017... es decir un cambio bastante heavy, no tengo errores pero al depurar no se me abre la página error 403.15... pero da igual pongo otra como inicial, pero creo que por culpa de saltarme alguna página antes no me carga el .css

Comment: 403.15??? Creo que no he visto ese error en la vida. Probablemente esté relacionado con el problema que describes en tu pregunta, asi que tal vez deberías [edit] tu pregunta y añadir todo lo referente a ese error tambien en la pregunta.

Comment: voy!! Gracias! ^^

Comment: siento ponerlo en ingles, pero esto y asi es lo que me ha salido al googlear: "Search Results
Featured snippet from the web
403.15 - Forbidden: Client access licenses have exceeded limits on the web server. 403.16 - Client certificate is untrusted or invalid. 403.17 - Client certificate has expired or is not yet valid. 403.18 - Cannot execute requested URL in the current application pool."

Comment: mi error debería de ser este: 403.15 - Forbidden: Client access licenses have exceeded limits on the web server.  Pero no entiendo que es lo que excedo.. :S

Comment: Es decir yo creo que el error no es correcto, que tiene que fallar algo.. pero no tiene nada que ver con el 403.15...

Comment: Has comprobado si tu nueva versión de Framework es compatible con esa función? o en vez de subir de golpe has ido subiendo de versión poco a poco?

Comment: tiene que ver con las licencias de servidor, hsa visto si es compatible?

Comment: voy a probar de no cambiar el Framework y lanzarlo. Simplemente con el visual studio 2017.

Comment: Simplemente un comentario, a veces NO es posible abrir un projecto con una versión nueva de VS, ya que hay funcionalidades que no se soportan.

Comment: Estoy utilizando el visual studio 2008 y voy a probar de cambiar el framework